# PHP doesn't clear memory usage after function close

Tags: php, memory, yii

My project is about postgis which need very large amount of data.
And now i'm facing with the memory exhausted. So, i've tried to print out the memory usage to check it and found out that the memory doesn't clear after that function has end. Here is how i make a test.

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($polyLine); $i++){
        echo "BEGIN USE:" .memory_get_usage() . " - PEAK: " . memory_get_peak_usage() . "<br/>";
        $orderPolyLine[$i][] = Utils::mergeLinestringsAfterOffset($polyLine[$i], $overlapPaths[$i]->geom);
        echo "AFTER USE:" .memory_get_usage() . " - PEAK: " . memory_get_peak_usage() . "<br/>";
        echo "------------------------- $i -----------------<br/>";
    }
```

and there is an echo before the `Utils::mergeLinestringsAfterOffset` has end

```
echo "IN FUNCTION USE:" .memory_get_usage() . " - PEAK: " . memory_get_peak_usage() . "<br/>";
```

and the output on the screen is following.

```
BEGIN USE:122273264 - PEAK: 122685192
IN FUNCTION USE:127493720 - PEAK: 127802344
AFTER USE:127438320 - PEAK: 127802344
------------------------- 0 -----------------
BEGIN USE:127438320 - PEAK: 127802344
IN FUNCTION USE:185303472 - PEAK: 186612304
AFTER USE:185060120 - PEAK: 186612304
------------------------- 1 -----------------
BEGIN USE:185060120 - PEAK: 186612304
IN FUNCTION USE:211663656 - PEAK: 212287472
AFTER USE:211528488 - PEAK: 212287472
------------------------- 2 -----------------
BEGIN USE:211528488 - PEAK: 212287472
IN FUNCTION USE:214108488 - PEAK: 214419800
AFTER USE:214071624 - PEAK: 214419800
------------------------- 3 -----------------
BEGIN USE:214071624 - PEAK: 214419800
IN FUNCTION USE:236060496 - PEAK: 236967592
AFTER USE:235916176 - PEAK: 236967592
------------------------- 4 -----------------
BEGIN USE:235916176 - PEAK: 236967592
IN FUNCTION USE:238352960 - PEAK: 238708584
AFTER USE:238312440 - PEAK: 238708584
------------------------- 5 -----------------
BEGIN USE:238312440 - PEAK: 238708584

( ! ) Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 438611 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dlt-gis/vendor/yiisoft/yii/framework/YiiBase.php on line 470
```

Should memory reduce in after use line? Or did i misconcept anything about php?
Thank you for your advice.

EDIT:

I also did unset the variable before the loop end but the memory still exhausted and not have any reduction in each loop.

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($polyLine); $i++){
        echo "BEGIN USE:" .memory_get_usage() . " - PEAK: " . memory_get_peak_usage() . "<br/>";
        $orderPolyLine[$i][] = Utils::mergeLinestringsAfterOffset($polyLine[$i], $overlapPaths[$i]->geom);
        unset($orderPolyLine);
        echo "AFTER USE:" .memory_get_usage() . " - PEAK: " . memory_get_peak_usage() . "<br/>";
        echo "------------------------- $i -----------------<br/>";
    }
```

Comment: `Utils::mergeLinestringsAfterOffset` being a static wont help, plus if its not clearing its properties your manipulating and not clearing data in each initialization of it, its going to leak

Comment: You're doing something with the functions output, is it possible that's where your memory usage is coming from? Does the memory usage drop if you unset that index and call the garbage collector?

Comment: @scragar I've put `unset($orderPolyLine)` before `echo AFTER USE` but the memory still exhausted with no drop in each loop. And how to call garbage collector by the way?
Thank you

Comment: @LozCheroneツ I did also tried change the static function to just normal function in the same file and it shows the same result, memory exhausted.

Comment: With the [gc_collect_cycles](http://php.net/gc_collect_cycles) method

Comment: found out that the garbage collector are doing just fine.
The real problem is in YiiBase.php file which has function debug_backtrace() and make memory exhausted from my super longggggggggg query... Turning debug off in Yii framework has fix this problem